# Continuous and preserves measurability $\implies$ preserves null sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a (Lebesgue-)measurable set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous function that preserves measurability ($A$ meausurable $\implies f(A)$ measurable).

**Prove:** for all $A \subset X$,$\space$$\lambda(A)=0 \implies \lambda(f(A)) = 0$ .

I'm totally stuck. Initially I made some progress but now I'm at a point where it feels like the statement shouldn't be true at all.

Additionally i'd like to know if the statement works for general topological measure spaces (or even just metric measure spaces). That is:

Let $X$ be a (Lebesgue-)measurable set of $Y$, Topological (or metric) measure space and $f:X \to Y$ continuous function that preserves measurability etc...

Comment: Hint: A set of positive measure contains a non-measurable subset, and any subset of a null-set is a null-set.

Comment: @DavidMitra Brilliant David! so simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove this by contrapositive:

Suppose that $f$ doesn't preserve null sets.  Then there is a set $f(N)$ that does not have zero measure.  That is, $f(N)$ must have a non-measurable subset $A$.

Now, consider $f^{-1}(A) \cap N$, which must be measure zero, by the completeness of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: "or is perhaps measurable itself"? We know $f(N)$ is measurable by hypothesis. +1, regardless, this is nice.

Comment: How does the result follow from your last line?

Comment: @JaneDoe the point is that $f^{-1}(A) \cap N$ is measurable (with measure zero), but $f[f^{-1}(A) \cap N] = A$ is non-measurable.

Comment: How do we get $f[f^{-1}(A) \cap N] = A$? In general, we can’t just take images over intersections (except when $f$ is injective).

Comment: I cannot edit my comment any longer but to clarify, I meant that all we have is $f[f^{-1}(A) \cap N] \subseteq A$, unless I am missing why this function is necessarily injective?

Comment: Note that $A \subset f(N)$.  Thus, there is a set $B \subset N$ for which $f(B) = A$.  We have $B \subset f^{-1}(A) \cap N$, which means that $f(B) = A \subseteq f[f^{-1}(A \cap N)]$.  We do not assume that $f$ is injective.

Comment: @JaneDoe I think the way I originally thought about it is as follows: $f|_N^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A) \cap N$ ($f|_N$ denotes the restriction of the map $f$ to the domain $N$).

Comment: Sorry if I’m being particularly obtuse (and I appreciate you clarifying a question that you answered 4 years ago) but... how do we get $B \subseteq f^{-1}(A) \cap N$ from the way you chose B?

Comment: @JaneDoe You're welcome.  $B \subset f^{-1}(A)$, since $f(x) \in A$ for every $x \in B$.  $B \subset N$ since $B$ was defined to be a subset of $N$.  So, $B \subset f^{-1}(A) \cap N$.  I think that you would get a better intuition for this by proving the general result $f|_N^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A) \cap N$, which I refer to in my previous comment.  I think it's easier to see that $f(f|_N^{-1}(A)) = A$ holds because $A$ is in the image of $f|_N$.

Answer (score 2):

For the convenience of others, I'll try present Omnomnomnom's complete idea.

Suppose $f$ preserves measurability and doesn’t preserve null sets. So there is an $N$ so that $N$ is a null set and $f(N)$ is not. Since $N$ is a null set, $N$ is measurable and so $f(N)$ is measurable with positive measure. This implies that there exists a nonmeasurable subset $A \subset f(N)$.

$A \subset f(N) = f|_{N}(N)$, so $$f(f|_{N}^{-1}(A)) = f|_{N}(f|_{N}^{-1}(A)) = A.$$

Since $f(f|_{N}^{-1}(A)) = A$, $f$ preserves measurability, and $A$ is nonmeasurable, we conclude $f|_{N}^{-1}(A)$ is nonmeasurable.

Since $N \cap f^{-1}(A) \subset N$, and $m(N) = 0$, completeness of the Lebesgue measure implies $N \cap f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable (with measure $0$).
But from

$$
\begin{align*}
x \in f|_{N}^{-1}(A) &\Leftrightarrow x \in N \mathrm{\ and\ } f|_{N}(x) \in A \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow x \in N \cap f^{-1}(A),
\end{align*}
$$

we find $f|_{N}^{-1}(A) = N \cap f^{-1}(A),$ a contradiction.

Note that we didn't use continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the hint from @David Mitra. Knowing that

> A set of positive measure contains a non-measurable subset

> Any subset of a null-set is a null-set

by the contrapositive of the first and using the second you can state that

> Let $A$ be a Lebesgue-measurable set. Every subset $B\subset A$ is measurable, if and only if, $m(A)=0$. Even more, $m(B)=0$.

Going back to proving the statement of the question, our strategy to show that $m(f(A))=0$ will be to show that every subset $D\subset f(A)$ is measurable. If we take pre-image: $f^{-1}(D)\subset A$. But we know that $m(A)=0$, so by the proposition before said, $f^{-1}(D)$ is measurable. Taking the image of the previous set $D=f(f^{-1}(D))$. But as $f$ preserves measurable sets and $f^{-1}(D)$ is, so do $D$.

We never used the continuity of $f$.