# A counterexample for preserves null sets $\Rightarrow$ preserves measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In this post [Continuous and preserves measurability $\implies$ preserves null sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1026330/444923) the proofs demonstrate that *preserves measurability $\Rightarrow$ preserves null sets* does not depend on continuity. There is a well known theorem that for continuous functions these properties are equivalent, and in the proof I know of the above statement's converse depends on continuity; the proof depends on the fact that continuous functions map $F_\sigma$ sets to $F_\sigma$ sets. So I suppose *preserves null sets $\not\Rightarrow$ preserves measurability* in the general case.

Does there exist a counterexample proving this?

---

I think it's interesting that "Lusin's False $F_\sigma$ Theorem" would *naturally* imply this without the assumption of continuity. I.e., the false statement that for measurable $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a continuous $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and an $F_\sigma$ set $F \subset E$ such that $f|_{F} = g|_{F}$ and $m(E - F) = 0$. Suppose this and in addition that $f$ is null set preserving. Then $f|_F$ is null set preserving, so $g|_F$ is, and our known theorem in the context of continuity implies $g|_{F}$ is measurability preserving. So for measurable $A \subset E$, the set $f(A \cap F) = f|_F(A) = g|_F(A)$ is measurable. Then $f(A) = f(A \cap (E - F)) \cup f(A \cap F)$ is a union of measurable sets, since $A \cap (E - F)$ is a null set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While remembering why "Lusin's False $F_\sigma$ Theorem" is false, I found a way to give a counterexample.

Consider a measurable set $E$ containing $0$ with a nonmeasurable subset $A \subset E$, which contains $0$. Where
$\chi_{A}$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$, consider $$f : E \to \mathbb{R},\ x \mapsto x\cdot\chi_{A}(x).$$

For any set $N$, $f(N) \subset N \cup \{0\}$. So if $m(N) = 0$ then $m(f(N)) = 0$, and we see $f$ is null set preserving. However, $f(E) = A$. So $f$ maps a measurable set onto a nonmeasurable set.

Note that $f$ is never continuous.

Comment: But $f$ is not measurable right?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Sorry for my belated response. I wrote this question while studying for qualifying exams, and never wanted to look back to that era.

Yes. I believe I was not assuming that $f$ is measurable. [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298226/109654) states that for Lebesgue measurable functions $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, preserving null sets is equivalent to preserving measurable sets. [Ben's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1026352/444923) shows one direction of this. I'm not finding any immediate reference for the other direction.